# Access to file on network drive asp net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I open file by asp core endpoint successfully:

```
        [HttpGet("files/{fileName}")]
        public IActionResult GetFile(string fileName)
        {
            var filePath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + "\\Files\\" + fileName;
            if (filePath == null) return NotFound();
            return PhysicalFile(filePath, MimeTypes.GetMimeType(filePath));
        }
```

The file is in the server local folder:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myProject\files
```

I want to do the same with network folder mounted as disk `R:\`:

```
var filePath = "R:\\Files\\" + fileName;
```

```
R:\files
```

But this do not works with error 500.
I also can open file from `R:\` directly by windows explorer with login & password.
So how to get access to the network drive file?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?? I have same scenario where i need to access shared drive from .Net Core api ! its becoming headache now.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get the network address which is mapped to R: Drive, then you can use it as the file/folder path in your code:

Since you require a password to access the files in this shared drive, you've got two options as explained in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496068/asp-net-read-files-from-a-password-protected-network-share)

1: Set AppPool user

> The "right" way to do this is to run the webserver's AppPool as the
> identity that can access the share. That way, the only credential
> storage is done securely in the IIS config (rather than in your code
> or in readable config files). Putting the webserver and fileserver in
> the same Windows domain (or different domains with trust) is the
> easiest way, but the "same username/password" thing should work there
> as well.

2: P/Invoke to WNetAddConnection2
This has a good implementation here [How To Access Network Drive Using C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-access-network-drive-using-c-sharp)

```
using System;  
using System.ComponentModel;  
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;  
using System.Net; 
public class ConnectToSharedFolder: IDisposable  
{  
    readonly string _networkName;  
  
    public ConnectToSharedFolder(string networkName, NetworkCredential credentials)  
    {  
        _networkName = networkName;  
  
        var netResource = new NetResource  
        {  
            Scope = ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork,  
            ResourceType = ResourceType.Disk,  
            DisplayType = ResourceDisplaytype.Share,  
            RemoteName = networkName  
        };  
  
        var userName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials.Domain)  
            ? credentials.UserName  
            : string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", credentials.Domain, credentials.UserName);  
  
        var result = WNetAddConnection2(  
            netResource,  
            credentials.Password,  
            userName,  
            0);  
  
        if (result != 0)  
        {  
            throw new Win32Exception(result, "Error connecting to remote share");  
        }  
    }  
  
    ~ConnectToSharedFolder()  
    {  
        Dispose(false);  
    }  
  
    public void Dispose()  
    {  
        Dispose(true);  
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);  
    }  
  
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)  
    {  
        WNetCancelConnection2(_networkName, 0, true);  
    }  
  
    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]  
    private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NetResource netResource,  
        string password, string username, int flags);  
  
    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]  
    private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string name, int flags,  
        bool force);  
  
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]  
    public class NetResource  
    {  
        public ResourceScope Scope;  
        public ResourceType ResourceType;  
        public ResourceDisplaytype DisplayType;  
        public int Usage;  
        public string LocalName;  
        public string RemoteName;  
        public string Comment;  
        public string Provider;  
    }  
  
    public enum ResourceScope : int  
    {  
        Connected = 1,  
        GlobalNetwork,  
        Remembered,  
        Recent,  
        Context  
    };  
  
    public enum ResourceType : int  
    {  
        Any = 0,  
        Disk = 1,  
        Print = 2,  
        Reserved = 8,  
    }  
  
    public enum ResourceDisplaytype : int  
    {  
        Generic = 0x0,  
        Domain = 0x01,  
        Server = 0x02,  
        Share = 0x03,  
        File = 0x04,  
        Group = 0x05,  
        Network = 0x06,  
        Root = 0x07,  
        Shareadmin = 0x08,  
        Directory = 0x09,  
        Tree = 0x0a,  
        Ndscontainer = 0x0b  
    }  
}  

public string networkPath = @"\\{Your IP or Folder Name of Network}\Shared Data";  
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"{User Name}", "{Password}");  
public string myNetworkPath = string.Empty;

public byte[] DownloadFileByte(string DownloadURL)  
{  
    byte[] fileBytes = null;  
  
    using (new ConnectToSharedFolder(networkPath, credentials))  
    {  
        var fileList = Directory.GetDirectories(networkPath);  
  
        foreach (var item in fileList) { if (item.Contains("ClientDocuments")) { myNetworkPath = item; } }  
  
        myNetworkPath = myNetworkPath + DownloadURL;  
  
        try  
        {  
            fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(myNetworkPath);  
        }  
        catch (Exception ex)  
        {  
            string Message = ex.Message.ToString();  
        }  
    }  
  
    return fileBytes;  
}
```

Comment: If I use 1st way. `nslookup [myipaddress]` gives me `Non-existent domain`. Also trying [this way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities#securing-resources) on web-server gives error at this step `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` — can not find object.

Comment: Also trying to create user on web-server with same log/pass as at fileserver gives password policy error — it is too short/simple.

Comment: The user doesn't have to have the same log/pass as fileserver, just correct rights to access the fileserver

Comment: Where/how could be this done? In IIS my app pool is set as ApplicationPoolIdentity.

Comment: https://campuslogicinc.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/5000713210-changing-identity-user-for-iis-application-pool
try selecting custom account and enter the username password you use for accessing network share.  Also ensure this user as access to the website folder

Comment: Trouble with 2nd part — can not join to domain. Without domain ADUC has no items. Any idea?